# Select entities without children

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, entity-relationship

I have a DB table containg both Quotations and Invoices entities. I save them in the same table, because in the project, quotation and invoice are the same kind of data, quotation is just prior to invoice. We can generate an invoice from a quotation, and invoice will receive the same data as his parent quotation. So I have a field parent_id, self referencing his parent. And I can tell if the table row is an invoice or a quotation from the "type" field. 1 = invoice, 2  = quotation.

Now I want to extract quotations having a chilg invoice, and quotations NOT having a child invoice.
For quotations having a child, I did the following, and it works :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('COUNT(q.id) AS number')
        ->join('i.parent', 'q')
        ->where('q.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->andWhere('q.statut > :statut_draft')
        ->setParameter('statut_draft', 0)
        ->andWhere('q.type = :type')
        ->setParameter('type', 2)
        ;
```

But I have no idea how to select quotations having no child. Something with

```
SELECT COUNT(q.id) FROM Table WHERE q.id NOT IN (SELECT i.parent_id FROM Table WHERE type = 1)
```

?

No way to do that without sub query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine allows you to use subqueries. Try this

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('COUNT(q.id) AS number')
        ->where('q.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyEntity q2 
            WHERE q2.type = 1 AND q2.parent = q)')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
```

Comment: I just came back to this feature, and I tried your solution. It returned me a `Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField` error, so I tried to get rid of these IDENTITY filters, and it works : `->andWhere('NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EvoBackendBundle:Invoice i WHERE i.type = 1 AND i.parent = q)')`. Thank you.